# Memory comsume of spring statemachine

Tags: spring-statemachine

I have used the spring statemachine to develop a game, in the peak hour, it will create about 5000 state machine, each state machine has about 25 state. But from a performance test, we notice that there are many object created, it is memory consumed and decrease the gc performance.
For my option, there are some object are inmutable like ObjectState, it can be reused for all the state machine. But it is created for each.

Is it a performance issue of spring state machine? Or is it my mis-usage?

```
10: 104192  10002432    org.springframework.statemachine.state.ObjectState
15: 208398  6668736 org.springframework.statemachine.support.OrderedCompositeItem
17: 397839  6365424 org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationAwareOrderComparator
18: 189440  6062080 org.springframework.statemachine.listener.OrderedComposite
26: 71040   4546560 org.springframework.statemachine.trigger.TimerTrigger
27: 89984   4319232 org.springframework.statemachine.transition.DefaultExternalTransition
30: 203648  3258368 org.springframework.statemachine.action.CompositeActionListener
42: 71040   1704960 org.springframework.statemachine.support.DefaultStateMachineExecutor$2
45: 104192  1667072 org.springframework.statemachine.support.AbstractStateMachine$4
46: 104192  1667072 org.springframework.statemachine.state.CompositeStateListener
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, those are created for every machine. It's interesting idea if those could be created once and then somehow shared between other instances as it would definitely reduce garbage. Would you mind creating a gh issue for this?